# How to @mention a bot using REST APIs?

Tags: google-hangouts

Using REST APIs, I'm able to @mention a **human** user in a chat space/room with the service account of a bot.

For example, the following API call posts a message in space(ID: *xyx*) tagging the user with ID 118194077000688478880.

```
API: POST https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=spaces/xyz}/messages
Body: { 'text' : '<users/118194077000688478880> sample message' }
```

However, I don't know how to tag a bot in a message using the same API

I inspected the browser and got the bot ID. I tried the following combinations and it didn't work. Suppose the bot ID is 1234567890

```
{ 'text' : '<users/1234567890> sample message' }
{ 'text' : '<bots/1234567890> sample message' }
{ 'text' : '<users/bots/1234567890> sample message' }
```

Kindly let me know if it's possible. If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to @mention a bot from a message sent via a webhook in Hangouts Chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216679/is-it-possible-to-mention-a-bot-from-a-message-sent-via-a-webhook-in-hangouts-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done, by design, so says Google. Pretty frustating if you ask me.

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>   Currently it is intended for bots only to be mentioned manually by a user. This is done in order to prevent potential abuse, especially in situations where a bot could @mention and send commands to other bots. This behavior is intended, but you may submit a feature request for this change. Be sure to include use cases for this functionality.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109759261