# Is it possible to @mention a bot from a message sent via a webhook in Hangouts Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a fully implemented bot to perform some incident management for my group. We also use webhook 'bots' to post system status updates to the same room. I would like to have the webhook messages `@mention` the full bot to kick off an incident in certain circumstances. When I test `@mentions` from the webhook using my own `user_id`, it works fine. When I try to `@mention` the bot using what looks to me to be its `user_id`, it doesn't get translated to the bot's username *and* it doesn't trigger an event.

Is there some other `user_id` format that I need to use or is this simply not an available feature at this time?

[chat log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq0zx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this is by design and is currently marked as "[won't fix](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109759261)"

I've submitted it as a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119377165).